# How to rename multiple files at once by removing a varying part in the file name on Windows?

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a windows folder having 500+ files with file names ending with the string " 203"
 Example: 
 1X 203.bmp 
2X 203.bmp 
1086 203.bmp 
25G 203.bmp 
...

How can i bulk rename all files in this folder, removing the " 203" string from the file names? Files after renaming should be like this.. 
 1X.bmp 
2X.bmp 
1086.bmp 
25G.bmp

Comment: Have you thought of using a Perl program's glob and mv (ie: rename too) ? Its almost a 1 liner.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208254/renaming-a-group-of-files-at-the-same-time-using-a-regex-to-concatenate-a-numb

Comment: Consider using a tool like [ReNamer](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products&product=renamer) if this is a one off task. EDIT: TThere are many good renaming tools: http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool

Comment: For Perl, you could rename it by globing a list of files, then `$res = File::Copy::move ("$fr", "$to")` for the rename.

Comment: This was a one off task. ReNamer worked perfectly for me. THANK YOU Dean!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are running on Windows, you can take advantage of PowerShell:

```
dir | rename-item –newname { $_.name –ireplace '(.+?) 203\.bmp$','$1.bmp' }
```

#### Description

```
dir          => list the content of the current directory
 |           => send each found element to the next command
rename-item  => rename an element in a Windows PowerShell provider namespaceject
–newname     => specify the name of the renamed file
{
    $_               => points to an object representing the actual file
   .name             => the name property of the automatic variable
   -ireplace         => perform a insensitive replace
   '(.+?) 203\.bmp$' => here comes the regex for matching the desired files
   '$1.bmp'          => the replacement string
}
```

You must run this command inside a power shell. Here is how to start it:

[image: how to launch powershell on Windows 7?]

Then `cd` into you dir from the Powershell window:

[image: Change to the directory containing the files to be renamed from powershell window]

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /a-d "* 203.bmp"') do @set "name=%i"&call set "name=%name: 203.bmp=.bmp%"&call ren "%i" "%name%"&set "name="
```

**directly from the prompt** as a batch one-liner

(I'd suggest you try it on a (part-)copy of your directory first though)

Comment: Your CALL trick to simulate delayed expansoin is broken - you need to double the percents.

Comment: @dbenham: not from the prompt it isn't!. Now if it was a line in a batch file - that's another matter, but directly from the prompt - as posted! (I've edited the bold text to include `directly`)

Comment: Ooh - my bad. But the variable may already exist prior to executing the command, which would cause it to fail. That can be fixed by putting a caret anywhere within the variable name - for example: `call set "name=%^name: 204.bmp=.bmp%"`

Answer (score 0):

For the people who are looking for **software tool** based solution instead of writing batch script.

Try the free tool(Windows only): **Bulk Rename Utility**

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

[image]